# how to call external css file in html.erb in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to call a css file in one of my html page in my rails application:

I am using rails 6 so I do not have the assets pipeline. So I created the folder assets under vendor and then the folder stylesheets. Finally I put the style.css under the folder `vendor/assets/stylesheets/`

Also, I have import it in the app/assets/application.css:
`@import "vendor/assets/stylesheets/style.css";`

But after calling it with the code below:

```
<link href="vendor/assets/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

it does not work.

Comment: What you have configured in application layout?

Comment: What does not work, is the stylesheet not included or the styles not applied?

Comment: I wanted to see what you have used to include js and css? I assume you have used `javascript_pack_tag` and `stylesheet_pack_tag`. Also make sure webpack can resolved your local assets https://github.com/rails/webpacker#resolved

Comment: Sorry I think it is because I did not include css.. How can I include it in webpacker?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Rails 6 too.
I don't know why you don't have the asset pipeline. My asset folder is under app folder.

I think the correct way to have a custom view is to generate new controller by using this command:

```
rails g controller controllername
```

Then you will have new view and stylesheets with your controllername:

- View is under app/views/controllername/
- Stylesheet is under app/assets/stylesheets/controllername.scss

Go to your controllername.css and style your own scss / css
After that go to your view and import the styles in your html.erb with:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "controllername" %>
```